# Azure: Resource not found in blob_client

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to delete my **azure blob** using the python script and for that I am using **BlobClient** from the library azure.storage.

Here is the code, I am trying to run:

```
import json, sys, os, time
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, PublicAccess, BlobClient


endpoint = os.environ['COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT']
subscription_key = os.environ['COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY']

text_recognition_url = endpoint + "/vision/v3.0/read/analyze"

file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")
image_url = "https://textimage.blob.core.windows.net/handwritten-text/" + file_name

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url=image_url)

blob_client.delete_blob()
print("Done")
```

Although, the blob and the container exists in the azure storage account, it throws me the following error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The specified resource does not exist.
```

Where I am I wrong?

What can be the better way to delete a particular open blob using python script?

Comment: Please dont do like this...I will update an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.getenv('str'))
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("test", "test.txt")
blob_client.delete_blob()
```

Above code works fine on my side.(You can replace the container name and blob name with dynamic value.)

And have a look of the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#methods

When you face `NoneType object has no attribute 'rstrip'`, that means you should give the method the connection string.

Comment: Thanks, just a little change was there: instead of **os.getenv('str')**, providing the value of connection string directly worked for me. Former was giving an error of `NoneType object has no attribute 'rstrip'`.

Comment: @nipan09 This problem should comes from the parameter in from_connection_string() method is null. Have you already give the connection string? It should get from this place: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ZR6.png

Comment: I already set that connection string in my environment variable, I guess that's why it worked.